# How to change file content upon Reading?

Tags: php, html

This is my requirement. I have a fixed file. "http://file.com/image.png". Upon opening this image everytime, there should be some random image instead.

If not, how do I just change the contents of the file had it been ".txt"

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=RY-5Uo3xBMPVtQbQx4G4CQ#q=php+generate+image&safe=off

Comment: What do u need? unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample script that generates a random image (just noise) on each load.

It needs the GD library to run.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");

$width = 200;
$height = 200;

$im = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

// loop each pixel
for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++) {
    for($y=0;$y<$height;$y++) {
        // should we draw a dot
        if(rand(0, 1)==1) imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $color);
    }
}

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the resource dynamic (served by a server-side processing such as php). URL rewriting is the key here for keeping the same URL.